# an algorithm with some arithmetics

Tags: algorithm

I want to write a particular function which does some calculation but i have no idea what the algorithm should be:

**Requirement**
I want to write a function in which you pass in a number and it returns a value from 0 to 1.
if i pass in a 0, it returns a 1 and as you increase the value of the input the output gets closer to 0.

This is similar to a y = 1/x function

but i want to set markers such as if the input is 300, it returns a 0.75 and if it is 600 it returns a 0.5

Is there such a formula which can help me do this?

Comment: This would be more on-topic for http://mathematics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, the vague title is not going to be helpful to anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. You mean you want it to behave like 1/x, but you want certain pre-defined values to give pre-defined results? Do you have an array of these pre-defined (x,y) pairs? And do the results need to be unique? (e.g., is the function intended to be a strictly decreasing function?) Does the array of pre-defined pairs change over time, or are they fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a function which does this!

I used Lagrangian Interpolation but it's not very simple. Instead, another (far more simple) answer that works only until 600;

```
              f(x)=-(x-1200)/1200
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know range high value, say for example 1200

The output should be 1-(300/1200) = 1 - 0.25 = 0.75

For input x, Formula is `1 - (x/Rangehighvalue)`